# jquery - get my autocomplete script to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I know this question has been asked a million times on the net and I am sure my post is going to get marked as a duplicate but I have been racking my brain for 2 days trying to get a simple script to work and I cant.

I know that if someone can get my jfiddle to work that will give me a basis to go off of and move on with my problem. From my understanding this is the most basic form of autocomplete I can have to get it to work.

Can someone help me out please

[jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78fptu6e/)

Here are the basics of what I have so far which does not work

```
$('#searchsong').autocomplete({
    source:["test","this","that","another"],
    minLength:2,
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="searchsong" id="searchsong" name="searchsong">
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a library that provides the autocomplete functionality.

Comment: this is like the 10th question today i have seen with the asker having no clue about the very basics of programming. i think StackOverflow has reached popularity top and quality bottom. That's what happens when venture capitals comes to your project.

Comment: auto complete method is not implemented in jquery.js. they are implemented in Jquery-UI please include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> after jquery.js

Comment: Im sorry @sharky but we all miss something sometimes and I am new to jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your dev console you'll see the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, which means a function command is not being interpreted as such. Since you only have an `autocomplete` call, that must be it. So your next step is to see if Jquery has `autocomplete` built into it (spoiler: no), and a quick search will tell you it belongs to Jquery-UI library.

So - you are missing the `Jquery-UI` library for the `autocomplete` function to work, I added it to this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78fptu6e/3/).

You can get the versions from [Here](https://code.jquery.com/ui/).

Comment: @CesarBielich Well it worked, but didn't have the pretty CSS attached. I added that as well, you can check it out now.

Comment: Im not seeing the css

Comment: @CesarBielich Did you click the fiddle link again ? It should have the `/3/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: I did and there is no CSS

Comment: @CesarBielich There are two libraries attached on the left at external resources.

Comment: I did and I see no CSS I must be blind or something

Comment: @CesarBielich Try to type in at the text box, do you see it working now?

Comment: @CesarBielich Great :)

Answer (score 0):

Here. I have updated the fiddle. You need to include jQuery UI and put all your code inside document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchsong').autocomplete({
        source:["test","this","that","another"],
        minLength:2,
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/78fptu6e/2/.